# Minecraft Plugin - How to teleport a player without requiring operator

Tags: java, minecraft

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("home")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player p = (Player) sender;

                double x = p.getLocation().getX();
                double y = p.getLocation().getY();
                double z = p.getLocation().getZ();

                TextComponent message = new TextComponent("[Click ME]");
                message.setColor(ChatColor.GOLD);
                message.setBold(true);
                message.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/tp " + p.getName() + " " + (int)x + " " + (int)y + " " + (int)z));
                message.setHoverEvent(new HoverEvent(HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT,
                        new ComponentBuilder("Click HERE").color(ChatColor.GRAY).italic(true).create()));

                p.teleport(p.getBedSpawnLocation());

                p.spigot().sendMessage(message);
                p.sendMessage("You have arrived home successfully");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I don't know how to teleport without being an operator.

I want to move to the bed when using the command, and move to the position before using the command when clicking [Click ME].

Comment: For those of us who may be ignorant, please clarify just what you mean by "tp" and "op".

Comment: tp means teleport, and op means Overpowered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @rorack isn't OP - operator when it comes to Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that command executed by clicking a message are always executed by the user who clicked.

A way to solve that issue is to use an [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that has Player has a Key and Location as a value. Each time a player execute the command, you add couple (player, location) to the HashMap, this way you can recover player saved position at any time.

Then you create a new command (/backtohome for example) and make create it to recover player saved position from the HashMap and teleport it back.

Code :

```
private Map<Player, Location> positions = new HashMap<>();

@Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("home")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player p = (Player) sender;

                double x = p.getLocation().getX();
                double y = p.getLocation().getY();
                double z = p.getLocation().getZ();

                TextComponent message = new TextComponent("[Click ME]");
                message.setColor(ChatColor.GOLD);
                message.setBold(true);
                message.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/backtohome");
                message.setHoverEvent(new HoverEvent(HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT,
                        new ComponentBuilder("Click HERE").color(ChatColor.GRAY).italic(true).create()));

                p.teleport(p.getBedSpawnLocation());

                // Add player position to hashmap
                positions.put(p, p.getLocation());

                p.spigot().sendMessage(message);
                p.sendMessage("You have arrived home successfully");
            }
        } else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("backtohome")) {
            if(sender instanceof Player) {
                Player p = (Player) sender;
                // Verify back position exist
                if(!positions.containsKey(p)) return;
                // Teleport back
                p.teleport(positions.get(p));
                // Clear previous pos
                positions.remove(p);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```